# Memcacheq vs cronjob in memory consumption

Tags: php, cron, message-queue, daemon

Is it so memory consuming to have a daemon written on php (which listens/process a queue) comparing to crontab way of executing background tasks?

I have ~600 shops on one server under one engine. Some tasks shop-owner runs require a lot of time, so it is reasonable to fork them. Putting a task into cron works well, I just don't like up to 59 sec delay of start (restriction of cron). So I'd like to try queue system. I'm just afraid it will force me to run 600 php threads to listen/process those queues (shops are from different customers, I can't make a common daemon). Doesn't it automatically require some 600-1000MB more memory, which is then not a good choice comparing to cron (which only loads a process if it was planned).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting them into a cron with a 59-second delay, why not run them using the "at" daemon? You can simply use "at now" and they'll run immediately. See, for example,:

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?at

I certainly wouldn't consider running 600 threads in PHP as daemons simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks for sobering me :) Ok, "at" is something new for me, while I used "nohup" once. Is "nohup" something different in this case? Because exec("nohup php mytask.php") looks more straightforward than exec("echo 'php mytask.php' | at now");

Comment: nohup means that the process will not be killed when the user running it logs out; by itself, it wouldn't be enough to solve your problem, but if you add an ampersand (to make the nohup task run in the background), it might work. so that'd get you `exec("nohup php mytask.php &")`
See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup

Comment: Thanks Daan, sure I forgot to add &, and are those commands equivalent now?

Comment: I'm not a Linux guru, but I think processes run by the "at" daemon run under a different user, while "nohup" keeps them attached to your user. And for "nohup", if your script sends any output to STDOUT/STDERR, it may well hang, while the "at" daemon will probably send the output to /dev/null. Someone more knowledgeable about these matters may want to correct this, though.

Answer (score 1):

I've previously built queue-runners that ran as many as 75-100 separate PHP processes, using [supervisor](http://supervisord.org) to start as many as I wanted. Since they share so much common code, that is also shared by the OS, and not duplicated.

Running a few dozen, or more, maybe with some type of high-priority queue for the small, fast jobs and a subset of the workers that can happily run the large, slow ones.

I've written on the subject at [my tech blog, phpscaling.com](http://www.phpscaling.com/tag/beanstalkd/).